# Resnet50 produces different prediction when image loading and resizing is done with OpenCV

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, keras

I want to use Keras Resnet50 model using OpenCV for reading and resizing the input image.
I'm using the same preprocessing code from Keras (with OpenCV I need to convert to RGB since this is the format expected by preprocess_input()).
I get slightly different predictions using OpenCV and Keras image loading. I don't understand why the predictions are not the same.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import json
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import cv2

model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

img_path = '/home/me/squirle.jpg'

# Keras prediction
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted Keras:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])

# OpenCV prediction
imgcv = cv2.imread(img_path)
dim = (224, 224)
imgcv_resized = cv2.resize(imgcv, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
x = cv2.cvtColor(imgcv_resized , cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted OpenCV:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])

Predicted Keras: [('n02490219', 'marmoset', 0.28250763), ('n02356798', 'fox_squirrel', 0.25657368), ('n02494079', 'squirrel_monkey', 0.19992349)]
Predicted OpenCV: [('n02356798', 'fox_squirrel', 0.5161952), ('n02490219', 'marmoset', 0.21953616), ('n02494079', 'squirrel_monkey', 0.1160824)]
```

How can I use OpenCV `imread()` and `resize()` to get the same prediction as Keras image loading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# Keras prediction
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))

   # OpenCV prediction
imgcv = cv2.imread(img_path)
dim = (224, 224)
imgcv_resized = cv2.resize(imgcv, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

1. If you look attentively, the interpolation you specify in the case
   of cv2 is `cv2.INTER_LINEAR` (bilinear interpolation); however, by default,
   `image.load_img()` uses an `INTER_NEAREST` interpolation method.
2. `img_to_array(img)`. The `dtype` argument here is: None

> Default to None, in which case the global setting
> tf.keras.backend.floatx() is used (unless you changed it, it defaults
> to "float32")

Therefore, in `img_to_array(img)` you have an image that consists of `float32` values, while the `cv2.imread(img)` returns a numpy array of `uint8` values.

3. Ensure you convert to RGB from BGR, as OpenCV loads directly into BGR format. You can use `image = image[:,:,::-1]` or `image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`; otherwise you will have the R and B channels reversed resulting in an incorrect comparison.

Since the preprocessing that you apply is the same in both cases, the only differences are the ones that I mentioned above; adapting those changes should ensure reproducibility.

There is one observation I would like to make: provided that one uses a library (`cv2` in this case) which automatically (and arguably only loads ints) instead of floats, the only correct way is to cast the first prediction array (Keras) to `uint8` because by casting the latter to `float32`, the possible difference in information is lost. For example, with `cv2` you load to `uint8`, and by casting instead of `233` you get `233.0`. However, maybe the initial pixel value was `233,3` but this was lost due to the first conversion.

Comment: Thank you Timbus. Indeed changing to INTER_NEAREST and adding 
resized_image = resized_image.astype(np.float32) improved inference: Predicted opencv: [('n02356798', 'fox_squirrel', 0.57044667).    Predicted keras: [('n02356798', 'fox_squirrel', 0.5161952)

Comment: Interesting that they still are not the same. I assume that the only correct way is to cast the first Keras array to uint8 because by casting the latter to float32, the possible difference in information is lost. For example, with cv2 you load to uint8, and by casting instead of 233 you get 233.0. However, maybe the initial value was 233,3 but this was lost due to the first conversion.

Comment: What I mean is that (in my opinion) the only correct way to test is to cast the first keras array to uint8 instead of casting the second cv2 to float32.

Comment: I suspect that is where the smaller difference now comes from, having some integer values converted instead of floats.

Comment: Yes. It makes sense to cast both to uint8. This makes both predictions identical but less accurate :(

Comment: cv2.imread( path, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH), maybe this solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Keras load image in **RGB** format, whereas OpenCV loads images in **BGR** format.

The [preprocessing function](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py) for [ResNet50](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/resnet.py) uses the **caffe** setting, it expect the image in **RGB** format, and applies the following:

1. Reverse the channels (RGB -> BGR)
2. Subtract [103.939, 116.779, 123.68] from the respective values

Since the values to be subtracted are different for each channel, the channel order is important. Furthermore, the layers of a *pretrained* ResNet50 model have been trained assuming a certain order.

Therefore you must reverse the order of the channels from **BGR** to **RGB** when loading an image using OpenCV

```
imgcv_resized =  imgcv_resized[:,:,::-1]
```